# HTML Forms input box and upload

Tags: html, forms

A tutorial I'm following created a form using the code below. The teacher's form has a space to enter text and the ability to upload data, but when I tried it, it only allowed me to browse/upload. There's no box to input text.

There's a link to my site here. http://quoralist.com/sandbox/upload.php

Any ideas why my form doesn't give me space to input text?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>


    <form action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

    <input type="file" name="file_upload" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />

    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using Google Chrome or Safari browser :-) Try with IE or FireFox. The `<input type="file">` tag is special and the way it is rendered is browser dependent. Here's [an article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) which illustrates how this tag could be styled so that it looks the same among all browsers.

Comment: thanks, do you know a way to construct the form so that it would work as intended in Chrome?

Comment: @Michael, you may take a look at the [following article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html).